# YOLOV5 with OPENVINO on CPU

Tags: computer-vision, frame-rate, openvino, yolov4, yolov5

I am trying to test:

only yolov5 without openvino : ~ 4 FPS 
yolov5 with openvino  : ~ 2 FPS

That is abnormal, can you give me any suggest or any comparison between two methods if you already compared between them.

Answer (score 3):

YOLOv5 is officially validated and supported on OpenVINO 2021.4. Might be the result that you obtained is based on a non-validated version. As such, I would recommend you to use the latest version of OpenVINO Toolkit.
In addition, YOLOv5 is available in four models, namely s, m, l, and x, each one of them offering different detection accuracy and performance. Refer to [YOLOv5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5#why-yolov5) for more information.

Comment: Thank  you so much, I don't found this version of yolo, I have seen just yolov3 and yolov4 can you give the link ?

Comment: You may refer to the following link:
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Comment: from official website   https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/workbench_docs_Workbench_DG_Configure_Accuracy_Settings.html 
NOTE: YOLO models of other versions, like YOLO V3 or YOLO V5, are not supported.